# Gradle Milestone 5 shows error about a missing artifact *#*!*.*

Tags: java, gradle, artifact

How can I resolved this error that I see in Gradle after upgrading to Milestone 5:

```
:nodes-all:war
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    a required artifact is not listed by module descriptor: *#*!*.*
```

Comment: any idea anybody? this is new in the new gradle 1.0-M5

Comment: I also have the same problem :( It's a simple project import jgrapht 0.73 from the default repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gone after upgrading to gradle  milestone 6 and after... not sure what caused it. I checked for empty dependencies as Ben suggested but that wasn't it. Anyways... problem some bug that just got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem because I was importing:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.linkedin-j:linkedin-j:1.0.416'
```

I should have been importing:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.linkedin-j:linkedin-j-core:1.0.416'
```

The difference here is that the first is a parent project not actually containing any jars of its own.  If I downgraded to M3 it didn't spit any warnings on to the screen, but the real fix was to point at the right jar in the Maven repository.